# Geonetwork 2.10: creating metadata for documents (reports, etc.)

Tags: geonetwork, template

I am using geonetwork 2.10, and I would need to create meta data for documents such as reports.

Which template am I supposed to use?
The only template I found which looks close enough to me is "template for map - Use this template to describe a static map (eg. PDF or image) or an interactive map" from ISO 19139.

Can you suggest me another template?